# Did vs was doing vs had done vs had been doing

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect, past-simple, past-continuous

> I *worked* a teacher before but now I work a translator.

What would be the slight difference if, instead of *worked*, we say *was working, had worked, had been working*?

What does each tense mean and imply here?

Comment: I think it should be *"worked **as** a teacher.. work **as** a translator"*

Comment: You can use either past or past perfect tense. But I'd prefer past tense because perfect tense is not needed. The progressive form(-ing) implies the continuity but if I were you, I would use past simple.

Comment: Thank you but why not was working ?

Comment: I just think it's not suitable to emphasize the continuity when you dont have the time period. It'd sound better if you say *"I was working as a teacher for a year.."*

Comment: Thanks so is "was working"equals I had been working for a year" ? Stresses the continuity ?

Comment: Yes, but perfect tense("had been working") is not required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, the difference is when you had decided to end the action.

Had the action ended in the past before another action that had already ended as well, you would use past perfect (had + past participle).

Had the action ended *simply* in the past before the current action, then I would use past *simple*.

See if my explanation was clear enough for you by quizzing yourself [here](https://www.ecenglish.com/learnenglish/lessons/past-simple-or-past-perfect).